# Android Firebase How to Read the Data from Current User ID?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code I want to read the current user id data from firebase.

```
DatabaseReference ref2;
ref2=db.getReference("HiringWalker").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

[image]

[image]

I want to read the current user id and -Lwg_.... all the data.

Comment: Hello, it is better if you copy the code and then ctrl + k the code

Comment: Please do NOT include images and links in questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct, but the fetch data is incorrect, should be modified from

```
ref2.addValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    infoList.clear();

    for (DataSnapshot infoSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
        for (DataSnapshot infomationsnap : infoSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            ReWalker rewalker = infomationsnap.getValue(ReWalker.class)
            infoList.add(rewalker);
        }
    }

});
```

to

```
ref2.addValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    infoList.clear();

    for (DataSnapshot infoSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
    {
        ReWalker rewalker = infoSnapshot.getValue(ReWalker.class)
        infoList.add(rewalker);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

This won't work because you need to go one level deeper, there is one more child that I unknown how you create it

```
ref2=db.getReference("HiringWalker").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

Do this instead

```
ref2=db.getReference("HiringWalker").child("ciu12tcL4RfzmC3T6Gdp64LgiZa2").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

Check where are you creating this `ciu12tcL4RfzmC3T6Gdp64LgiZa2` and replace that `.child("ciu12tcL4RfzmC3T6Gdp64LgiZa2")` with the current implementation that generates that random number